# pyinstaller как добавит картинки в ехе

Tags: python, pyinstaller

У меня вопрос. Как добавить картинки в конечный ехе файл в пайинсталер?

Comment: уточните о каких картинках вы говорите. картинка самого ехе ?

Comment: я работаю с библиотекой tkinter и в ней для изменения значка приложения в таск баре нужно указать иконку и я хочу вшить иконку в конечный exe